# PHP CLI capture BASH errors

Tags: php, bash

so i have pondered over this for days,
i have tried shell_exec and exec however i cannot tell if a command successfully executed or not, i was originally checking if the returned result was empty however this wouldn't work for a command like touch.

here are some example commands, i am trying to find out if the commands have successfully executed

- touch filename*
- iotop
- ls
- basically any unix command which the system supports.

here is my current code:

```
    $command = exec('sshpass -p '.$ssh_password.' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@'.$scan.' '.$usr_command_get,$returned);


   //var_dump($command);
   echo "\n";
   var_dump($returned);
   if($command == null){
       echo "no bloody error call back\n";
   }else{
       echo " success\n";
       echo $command;
   }
```

Comment: If you're talking about some generic unix command, that should return [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX) compatible status. So, if return code is greater then 0, it indicates process failed. If it's equals to 0, then execution was successful

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the messy code when i get time i am going to rewrite this so its alot nicer on the eyes and much better performance, anyway here is a working result for now to anyone who is looking to do what i was trying to do.

```
<?PHP

$failed_password_list = array('test','test1','test2','test3','test4','password');
$failed_password_array_count = count($failed_password_list);

error_reporting(0);
echo "\033[35m";
echo "Type in the Subnet you want to scan: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($handle);
$input_ip = trim($line);

echo "\033[36m";
echo "Type in the command you want to run: ";
$usr_command_query = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$usr_command_get = fgets($usr_command_query);

echo "\033[35m";
echo "executing";
echo "\033[0m\n";


if(filter_var($input_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE){

    echo "Error Ip is not valid please enter a valid ip";

}else{
echo "\033[32m";
    $i = 0;
//$p = 40;
$input = $input_ip;
$test = explode(".",$input);
$ssh_password = "password";
$executed = 0;
$online = 0;
$found_windows=0;
$found_linux=0;
while($i < 10){


$scan = $test[0].".".$test[1].".".$test[2].".".$i; 

exec("ping -c 2 " . $scan, $output, $result);

if ($result == 0){
    $online++;
    echo $scan." is online now finding OS \n";
$nmap_execute = shell_exec('nmap -O '.$scan);
$find_port   = '22/tcp';
$port_pos = strpos($nmap_execute, $find_port);
$end = $port_pos+25;
$new = substr($nmap_execute,$port_pos, +25);
$find_ssh   = 'ssh';
$ssh_pos = strpos($new, $find_ssh);
$end_index = $ssh_pos+3;
$sub = substr($new, 0, $end_index);
$result= str_replace(' ', '', $sub);
$find_linux   = 'gnu)';
$linux_pos = strpos($nmap_execute, $find_linux);
$linux_end = $linux_pos-20;
$linux = substr($nmap_execute,$linux_end, +23);
$find_windows   = 'Running:';
$windows_pos = strpos($nmap_execute, $find_windows);
$not_wanting = "OS details:";
$not_wanting_pos= strpos($nmap_execute,$not_wanting);
$windows_end = $not_wanting_pos;
$windows_start = $windows_pos;
$endthis = $not_wanting_pos - $windows_pos;
$windows = substr($nmap_execute,$windows_start, +$endthis);


if($windows_pos == TRUE){
    echo "OS found! \n";
    echo "\033[0m ";
    echo "\033[33m ".$scan." | Not Executing scripts | windows | ".$windows." \033[0m\n";
    $found_windows++;
}elseif($linux_pos == TRUE){
    $found_linux++;
    echo "OS found! \n" ;
    echo "\033[32m Unix | ".$linux." \n ";
    echo "Checking if port 22 is open\n";

    if($result === "22/tcpopenssh") {
    echo "Port 22 is open, connecting to remote server with credentials username:root password: \n";

    $returncode_failed ="";

    if($returncode_failed > 0 or $returncode_failed == null){

    $password_failed = 1;
    $failed_count = 0;
    //$failed_password_array_count = 6;



      while( ($password_failed > 0) && ($failed_count < $failed_password_array_count)){





          $command = exec('sshpass -p '.$failed_password_list[$failed_count].' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@'.$scan.' '.$usr_command_get,$myoutput,$returncode_failed);

         // var_dump($returncode_failed);
          $failed_count++;
          echo "trying next password \n";

          if($returncode_failed == 0){

              echo "Houstan we have launch! \n the result is \n";
              var_dump($myoutput);
              $executed++;
              break;

          }else{
              $password_failed = 1;
          }
      }


      echo "\n \n \n we have connected and executed the return code was ".$returncode_failed."\n";

}
else{
    echo " error";
}













 echo "\033[0m ";

}else{

   echo"\033[31m".$scan." Port 22 not open \033[0m\n";

} 




}else{
    echo "\033[31m Error doesnt seem to be a Windows or Linux system \033[0m \n";
}

}
else{

echo"\033[31m".$scan." is non contactable  \033[0m \n";
}



$i++;


}

if($executed > 0){

    echo "\033[33m Executed on ".$executed." out of the ". $online."  Machines  online \033[0m \n";
    echo "\033[33m Total Windows based machines found ".$found_windows." \033[0m \n";
    echo "\033[33m Total Linux based machines found ".$found_linux." \033[0m \n";
}else{
        echo("\033[33m Failed to execute on any machine \n");
     echo "\033[33m Executed on ".$executed." out of the ". $online." Machines online \033[0m \n";
    echo "\033[33m Total Windows based machines found ".$found_windows." \033[0m \n";
    echo "\033[33m Total Linux/Unix based machines found ".$found_linux." \033[0m \n";

}

}


?>
```